# Publishing large NPM packages

Tags: node.js, npm, v8

I'm trying to publish large npm package to a private Nexus 3 nmp repository, but the operation fails with the following error

```
npm ERR! node v7.7.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2

npm ERR! "toString()" failed
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

The problem is at V8 level and appears when building the request for publishing to Nexus.

It's not a good practice to publish large npm packages, but it's a third party plugin, and we need it for the project.

Is there a way to configure/patch V8 to support bigger file size ?

What is the request format for uploading npm package to nexus, so I can try to transform the package to encoded string using some other tool ?

Comment: How large is "large"? What file size are we talking about? Can you get any more details about why "toString()" failed? Are you sure it's a size limit that you're running into?

Comment: Yes, it's large. It's almost 1GB. There are a couple of posts regarding this issue, here is one of them https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9552. But I could't find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have published the package using CURL. The format of the request is

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
-H "Authorization: Basic ${authorization_token}"\
-H "Content-Length: ${actual size of the request body in bytes (just check the size of the request body file)}"\
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"\
-H "version: 8.1.1"\
-H "Accept: application/json"\
-H "npm-session: a972cb330cbacab5"\
-H "npm-in-ci: false"\
-H "User-Agent: node/v7.7.4"\
-H "Host: nexus.example.com:8081"\
-X PUT\
--data-binary @path_to_request_body_file\
--verbose\
http://nexus.example.com:8081/nexus/repository/npmrepo/ExamplePackage
```

nexus.example.com:8081 - are the actual nexus server host and port
authorization_token - is nexus authorization token
npmrepo - is a npm repository created through the Nexus Repository Manager, where the ExamplePackage will be published
path_to_request_body_file - should be file path to the request body file with format of the content as follows

```
{
  "_id": "ExamplePlugin",
  "name": "ExamplePlugin",
  "description": "Example Plugin",
  "dist-tags": {
    "latest": "0.1.0"
  },
  "versions": {
    "0.1.0": {
      "name": "ExamplePlugin",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "cordova_name": "ExamplePlugin",
      "description": "Example Plugin",
      "license": "Apache 2.0",
      "keywords": [
        "ExamplePlugin",
        "StackoverflowExample"
      ],
      "platforms": [
        "ios",
        "android"
      ],
      "engines": [],
      "dependencies": {},
      "maintainers": [
        {
          "name": "example_nexus_user",
          "email": "example.user@test.com"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "ExamplePlugin@0.1.0",
      "dist": {
        "shasum": "${shasum of the package archive file}",
        "tarball": "http://nexus.example.com:8081/nexus/repository/npmrepo/ExamplePlugin/-/ExamplePlugin-0.1.0.tgz"
     }
    }
  },
  "readme": "",
  "access": "public",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "example_nexus_user",
      "email": "example.user@test.com"
    }
  ],
  "_attachments": {
    "ExamplePlugin-0.1.0.tgz": {
      "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
      "data": "${Base64 encoded content of the npm package archive}",
      "length": "${actual size of the package archive in bytes}"
    }
  }
}
```

If the package archive file doesn't already exist, you can use `npm pack` to generate it.
I have used `openssl` to generate `base64` encoded string for the package archive `openssl base64 -in ExamplePlugin-0.1.0.tgz -out ExamplePluginEncoded`, but any other tool that supports large files may be used. 
I have generated the shasum for the package archive using `shasum -a 1 ExamplePlugin-0.1.0.tgz`, some other tool may also be used.

I got the format of the request and the JSON payload debugging the [npm-registry-client](https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-client), some of the fields are probably not required, some more options may also be available.

Answer (score 4):

`npm publish -timeout=9999999`

This helped me to publish 150mb package

Comment: This is not working for me and I don't see option `-timeout` documented in official docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish

Could you please provide the NPM version you are working with?

Comment: this worked for me when publishing a lib containing opencv ~100Mb

Comment: It helped me publish a package that was only 7Mb but for some reason (is the time spent in the `prepublish` hook counted towards the timeout?) had been timing out many times in a row.